# String without repeated characters

Tags: javascript, string, for-loop, if-statement, verification

I have r = to how many times can letter be repeated in a row and s = to string to check.
For example if s = "aaabbbccc777" and r = 2. result = "aabbcc77".
I need it to be dynamic and as easy and clean as possible.

Thanks for the help in advance.

```
let s = "bbbaaaccc777cdggg";
let r = 2;

const verification = (s, r) => {
    
}
verification(s, r);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over the string like this:

```
const verification = (s, r) => {
    let res = '', last = null, counter = 0;
    s.split('').forEach(char => {
        if (char == last)
            counter++;
        else {
            counter = 0;
            last = char;
        }
        if (counter < r)
            res += char;
    });    
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Thanks!! Clear and easy to understand how the problem is solved